# Check if a function draw/plot something

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, lattice

We are working with a `function` which could draw a plot or not.
I am looking for a solution to check if the function has a side effect of drawing.
I hope there is some `dev.*` solution to check it out.
The `inherits` could be used only for solutions which return reusable objects like `ggplot2`. On the other hand `boxplot` return a `list` and `plot` a NULL class.
I expect to check the `dev` precisely.
The extensive list of different graphics and non-graphics is provided.

```r
input_plots <- list(
  function() print(ggplot2::qplot(1)),
  function() lattice::densityplot(1),
  function() grid::grid.draw(ggplotify::as.grob(lattice::densityplot(1))),
  function() plot(1),
  function() boxplot(2),
  function() hist(1)
)

input_noplots <- list(
  function() list(),
  function() NULL,
  function() 2,
  function() NA
)

# We are working with a function which could draw a plot or not
all(vapply(input_plots, is.function, FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))
#> [1] TRUE
all(vapply(input_noplots, is.function, FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))
#> [1] TRUE

# all input_plots should be TRUE for is_draw
# all input_noplots should be FALSE for is_draw
is_draw <- function(fun){
  # inherits works only for functions returning proper instances
  # you can call a function fun()
  ...
  # return logical if the fun draw a plot
}

# all(vapply(input_plots, is_draw, FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))
# TRUE
# all(vapply(input_noplots, Negate(is_draw), FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))
# TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

VALIDATE SOLUTION:

```r
# all input_plots should be TRUE for is_draw
# all input_noplots should be FALSE for is_draw

# this function will clear your device
is_draw <- function(f) {
  try(dev.off(), silent = TRUE)
  # graphics.off() # close any current graphics devices
  cdev <- dev.cur()
  f()
  if (cdev != dev.cur()) {
    on.exit(dev.off())
    return(TRUE)
  }
  return(FALSE)
}

all(vapply(input_plots, is_draw, FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))
#> Warning: `qplot()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> [1] TRUE
# TRUE
all(vapply(input_noplots, Negate(is_draw), FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))
#> [1] TRUE
# TRUE

plot(1)
all(vapply(input_plots, is_draw, FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> [1] TRUE
# TRUE
all(vapply(input_noplots, Negate(is_draw), FUN.VALUE = logical(1)))
#> [1] TRUE
# TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: There's really no way to reliably do that without calling the function or something. I mean even `hist()` can be called with `hist(plot=TRUE)` or `hist(plot=FALSE)`. And `ggplot` functions don't actually draw anything. It's the `print()` method for the `ggplot` object that interacts with the graphics device. So your first `input_plots` should really be FALSE. Are you ok with running the function to observe the possible sideeffects? Or are you trying to find this out without running the function?

Comment: We can call each function inside. Yes with ggplot we have to print it, I updated the question. I added the `grid::grid.draw` to grob too.

Comment: Important comment is that it will NOT work for shiny `reactive` for base plots (non-reusable) and their second and next calls. Only the first reactive call for base plots will plot sth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you currently have no graphics device open, one way would be to check if the current device changed.

```
is_draw <- function(f) {
  graphics.off() # close any current graphics devices
  cdev <- dev.cur()
  f()
  if (cdev != dev.cur()) {
    on.exit(dev.off())
    return(TRUE)
  }
  return(FALSE)
}
```

Note that this depends on you being able to evaluate the function. This returns `FALSE` for your `lattice` example because, like `ggplot`, those plots only render when the `print()` method is called.

This method also closes the graphics device so the plot is lost, but you need to close it to see if a new one opens up

Comment: The catch is that this method only works as long as you have no graphics device open at the start. Otherwise the plotting function will not create a new graphics device, it will replace the latest one.

Comment: I made a small update to this function `try(dev.off(), silent = TRUE)` at the beginning. Please to consider to add it here too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @polkas I changed it to `graphics.off()` which will close all devices in case more than one is open.

Comment: Ones more thank you for your time and great solution.

Comment: One thing to look out for: any calls to par() will open a device even if the function doesn't eventually draw anything.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work on Rgui on Windows.  You can check whether it works in your environment. Zap all graphics devices using `dev.off` and then after running your code check the length of `dev.list()` .

```
for(d in dev.list()) dev.off()

x <- 3 # does not plot
length(dev.list())
## [1] 0

plot(0)  # plots
length(dev.list())
## [1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but in my opinion the second solution seem to be more suited.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using `recordPlot()`:

```r
is_draw <- function(f) { 
    plot(rnorm(10))
    pre <- recordPlot()
    f() 
    post <- recordPlot()
    !identical(pre, post) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting solution. I do not think you leave this `plot(rnorm(10))` there on purpose, or is it an alternative for `dev.off`. The function seems to work the same with out this plot call. Unfortunately the solution is not working for `lattice::densityplot(1)`.

Comment: That's to make sure that we start with a random state. Otherwise calling the same f() consecutively should give TRUE only for the first call, and FALSE for the rest (in practice that doesn't happen consistently, but I haven't checked why). Also, without any previous plot, the first call to recordPlot() might give an error.

Comment: And it's not supposed to work with `lattice::densityplot(1)`, or `ggplot2::qplot(1)`, etc., because these calls do not plot anything. They will only plot when print-ed, so you need `print(lattice::densityplot(1))`, etc. I think others have pointed this out earlier. Same with `hist(plot=TRUE)` and `hist(plot=FALSE)`.